# How to set Timestamp (pandas Datetime) to xlim of plot with FunctAnimation?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I want to limit my graph from left and set (the current time - 2 hours) to xlim. I tried to add to the "update" function this

```
self.ax.set_xlim(left=max(self.data.iloc[0, 0], self.data.iloc[-1, 0] - pd.Timedelta(hours=2)))
```

But this is doesn't work. Could anyone help me do this, please?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

def to_pd(wt, wf):
    p = pd.DataFrame({"Date": [wt], "Cost": [wf]})
    p["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(p["Date"], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    return p


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(18,8), dpi=90)

class Graph():
    def __init__(self):
        self.ax = fig.add_subplot()
        self.start_time = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.data = to_pd(self.start_time,0)
        self.line, = self.ax.plot(self.data.Date,self.data.Cost)

    def update(self,i):
        self.current_time = (self.data.iloc[-1,0]+pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        self.data = self.data.append(to_pd(self.current_time,(-1)**i))

        self.line.set_data(self.data.Date, self.data.Cost)

        self.ax.relim()
        self.ax.autoscale_view()

        return self.line,

object = Graph()
def animate(i):
    return object.update(i)

anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=200,interval=100, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved, but I think there is more convenient way. But, here what am done, just added it into the 'update' function, it's clear all old data:

```
if self.data.iloc[-1, 0] - pd.Timedelta(hours=2) >= self.data.iloc[0, 0]:
    self.data = self.data[self.data.Date > self.data.iloc[0, 0]]
```